# Calling variables from other files in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to import files and here is the situation.

file1.py contains:

```
from file2 import *
username = "steven"

action()
```

file2.py contains:

```
def action():
    print username
```

But i can't print the username because the variable 'username' is declared in file1 but not file2 (for the function uses the variable)

This is not the actual code, but can I not use variables from file1 in functions from file2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better approach is to not rely on globals from another module, and simply pass the name into the `file2.action()` function:

### file1.py

```
import file2

username = "steven"

file2.action(username)
```

### file2.py

```
def action(name):
    print name
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! So I don't have to type "import *" ? i can just import the file?

Comment: That's right. If you just `import file2`, then  you will need to *qualify* all names in file2 with `file2.`, such as the `file2.action` example. But that's a good thing, since you know where the `action` is going.

Comment: In this case, any function from `file2.py` which makes use of a variable from `file1.py` should have an argument to get it?

Answer (score 2):

What you intend, in the way you want,would require file1 import file2 and vice-versa -  in a plain code, that would lead to a circular import, which plainly does not work.

But besides that, if your functions, classes or methods on a file need to know about data that is on the context of a file that imported them, the right thing to do is to pass this data in as function parameters.

In your case, your "action"  function should be:

```
def action(username):
    print username
```

and on file1:

```
from file2 import action
username = "steven"

action(username)
```

(You also should avoid using "import *" as it hides where names come from when reading the code, making it hard to maintain)

Of course, Python being Python, there are work-arounds to do exactly what you want - you could create a special  decorator to use on your imported functions that would recreate your function from another file, pointing it to the global variables from the current module - but that would be just silly.

The "OOP" paradigm allows for one silly case which is more or less like what you are intending to do - where a method uses a class attribute - and if that attribute is overridden in a subclass, the method - even the original superclass method, will use the new attribute value - like in:

```
class A(object):
    username = ""
    def action(self):
         print self.__class__.username
```

and class  B could be defined in other file, as you intend to:

```
from file2 import A
class B(A):
    username = "Mike"

b = B()
b.action()
```

And now, just for giving you a complete answer - here is some code that will do what you want - but _don't do it - modify yoru functions to take parameters instead.

What can be done is having a function to read the global variables of the place from where it was called. That is not only "not a good pratice" - it is just wrong, except for some very well documented frameworks where "magic variable names" are used for configuration. Even when I find a framework with this bad habit, I tend to patch its functions so that I can pass the configuration explicitly via a function call.

```
from inspect import currentframe

def action():
    caller_frame = current_frame(1)
    caller_globals = caller_frame.f_globals
    print caller_globals["username"]
```

Answer (score 1):

But `file2.py` didn't import `file1.py`; how's it supposed to know that `username` even exists?

---

Incidentally, I try to avoid circular dependencies in my code (i.e. module x import module y, and module y imports module x), so simply importing `file1` into `file2` may not be the best solution.

Comment: The circular dependency would not even work in Python - not with a couple of "if"s in the module maincode that are aware of it at import time.

Answer (score 1):

No, file2 cannot access the global variables in file1 without explicitly importing them. This is actually a good thing, since otherwise, a project which imports a bunch of modules would easily be overwriting eachothers data accidentally.

Why not make the username an argument of the method?

file1.py:

```
from file2 import action
username = "steven"
action(username)
```

file2.py:

```
def action(username):
   print username
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you use classes, as they scale quite easily:

**file1.py**:

```
from file2 import ExtendedClass

class MyClass(object, ExtendedClass):
  def __init__(self):
    Object.__init__(self)
    self.username = 'steven'
```

**file2.py**:

```
class ExtendedClass:
  def action(self):
    print self.username
```

Even though somewhat hacky-methods exist and solve your problem, you'll appreciate classes once you use them.