# Cannot copy the filename browsed into the main program. Where can i write my main function where i have to write my piece of code. Exactly where?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-idle

I am new to trying this TKinter . I have to browse files and folders. What i need is to get the pathname of the files and folders i have browsed. i Am not not able to understand where to put my piece of code in this script? . How can i do it? or should i write a seperate  . Am stuck in here. I browsed through stack overflow many have problem of getting filenames returned back to their program s with no proper solution. Can anyone help me on this?Advance thanks.

```
from Tkinter import Tk, RIGHT, BOTH, RAISED,Label
from ttk import Frame, Button, Style
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox
import glob  
#global root
f1=""
f2=""

def FileBrowser():
    img1_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,title='Provide the Query Image ')
    global f1
    f1=img1_path
    #print img1_path

def PathBrowser():
    img2_path =tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root,title='Provide the path for Training Dataset ')
    global f2
    f2=img2_path
    #print img2_path

def matcher():
    imlist=glob.glob(f2)
    print imlist
    for file in imlist:
        print file


class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        global root
        self.parent.title("Medical CBIR")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")

        frame = Frame(self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
        w = Label(self, text="QUERY IMAGE")
        w.pack()
        style = Style()
        style.configure("TFrame", background="#333")        

        im = Image.open('D:/database/Mixture/1.png')
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        label1 = Label(self, image=img)
        label1.image = img
        label1.place(x=155, y=70)
        frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        Retrieve_Image=Button(self,text="Retrieve Related Images",command=matcher)
        Retrieve_Image.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)

        Training_Image = Button(self, text="Path of Training Images",command=PathBrowser)
        Training_Image.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)

        Test_image = Button(self,text="Browse Test_Image",command=FileBrowser)
        Test_image.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)




def main():
    global root
    root = Tk()
    #root.geometry("300x200+300+300")
    root.geometry("500x500")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() 

# Comparison.py(2nd file)
import cv2
import sys
import GUItkinter

img1_path =GUITKinter.FileBrowser()
img2_path =GUITKinter.PathBrowser()
imlist=glob.glob(f2)
for file in imlist:
     compare(img1_path,file) #Function to compare images for similarity
#display the retrieved results
```

Error: Bad window pathname in img1_path =GUITKinter.FileBrowser()

Comment: Kindly format the question properly. Also,what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @shaktimaan- I have my piece of code where i want the path name and filename to be copied fro tkinter but i am not able to use it because of some callback error.TKinter doesnt support it. how can i do it and where to place my piece of code in this program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to work out the code yourself. But what I'll do is provide you a way how to format your code & how to implement the problem you are having.

```
import tkFileDialog
from Tkinter import Tk,Button,StringVar,Entry

class MainClass():

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.parent=master
        self.mainfunc()

    def mainfunc(self):
            self.path_setup = StringVar()
            browse=Button(root,text="Browse",command=lambda:self.path_setup.set(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Image File",'.jpg')])))
            browse.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='E')

            path_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=self.path_setup,state='disabled')
            path_entry.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='E')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("My Program")
    root.wm_resizable(0,0)
    client = MainClass(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

It's a "piece" of code which I was working on. I have formatted it for you.

Hope this gets you going :)

Comment: @shaktimaan- I have edited my code. I have a seperate code written in some other page. In that page i have code for finding similarity between two images. I just wanted a GUI for my Program , but i am not able to copy the path of files  i browsed in TKinter into my  code of program

Comment: What do you mean by "other page"?

Comment: My piece of code lies in a File_comparison.py, The following code i have written here is stored in Tkinter.py , I want a GUI to select files and when i select the file i want the path of it to be copied into my File_comparison.py so that i can remove the hardcoding of typing in the filename path. But TKInter doesnt allow filenames to be returned. How can i merge these two files to give a good GUI .

Comment: @Jonas 1. **Never** name your file Tkinter.py. Its the name of the inbuilt Tkinter module.

2.Just import the other file & call its function which returns the filename. Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9252944)

Comment: @shaktiman. I Have tried that before, but was not able to link it. I have two files GUItkinter.py and comparison.py. GUItkinter.py is the one i have posted above.

Comment: @Jonas: Since your requirements have changed(i.e.,from getting pathname to getting variables from other file),I suggest you to ask another question. That way other users will also benefit. Thanks :)

Comment: @shaktimaan- it was really a great help from u, But i solved the code with some minor changes.  in Pathbrowser() i removed the " ' " and was able to get what i want.Thank you ShakthiMan(Gangadhar ) :p

Comment: @Jonas: ohh,so you know my secret.. :P